# Default Java annotation values: same instance by specification?

Tags: java

On my JRE, the following test passes:

```
public static @interface Bar {}

@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
public @interface Foo
{
    Bar value() default @Bar;
}

@Foo
public Object default1;

@Foo
public Object default2;

@Foo(@Bar)
public Object specified;

@Test
public void test() throws NoSuchFieldException, NoSuchMethodException
{
    Foo d1 = getClass().getField("default1").getAnnotation(Foo.class);
    Foo d2 = getClass().getField("default2").getAnnotation(Foo.class);
    Foo s = getClass().getField("specified").getAnnotation(Foo.class);
    Assert.assertSame(d1.value(), d2.value());
    Assert.assertNotSame(d1.value(), s.value());
}
```

Is the behavior behind both of these assertions specified by Java?  Is this a reliable condition to detect when a developer provided a value (albiet one that `equals` the default)?

Comment: [Related?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37853188/why-are-annotation-string-values-not-interned)

Comment: They're definitely using the same proxies internally to represent default valued annotations, and a different proxy to represent one manually specified.  I would say though that this is different than *instances*, since you can't ever *instantiate* an annotation (or interface, for that matter).

Comment: @shmosel That was actually quite helpful.  The default value for annotations are serialized into the method as `byte[]`.  Obviously they're caching an instance, but I can't imagine anyone putting that requirement into a specification.  Thanks!

Comment: @Makoto You *can* create an instance of an `Annotation`, just like you can create an instance of `java.util.Map`.  Obviously we mean we're creating an instance of a class that implements the interface, but the resulting object *is* an instance of that interface.  Walk around saying "my method takes one argument: a *proxy* of `java.util.Map`" and you're gonna get weird looks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looking at how default values for annotation members are stored in Oracle's implementation (`java.lang.reflect.Method#annotationDefault`), it's doubtful implementations would be *required* to cache a single instance.